# attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats' error in roblox studio

Tags: lua, scripting, game-development, roblox

I'm making a game where you ram cars into houses and it unanchored the parts that are touched by a part in the front of the car. I want to have it so that whenever you unanchor a part, you get a coin

```lua
local HitPart = script.Parent

local function onTouch(otherPart)

    local player = otherPart.Parent

    if otherPart then

        local player = game.Players:FindFirstChild(otherPart.Parent.Name)

        if otherPart then

            game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.coins.Value = game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.coins.Value + 1 

        end

    end
end

HitPart.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```

HitPart is the part that is touching the other parts. However, I keep getting an attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'" error. does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It means it doesn't exist. If it does, make sure to get capitalization correct.